# PDF Attachment As Part of PUT Request

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am looking for some ideas here. I have a requirement where a client will do a PUT HTTP request that contains some JSON data  as a form field eg.

```
{
    "List": {
        "ListItems": [
            {
                "ItemCaption": "No",
                "ItemValue": "N"
            },
            {
                "ItemCaption": "Yes",
                "ItemValue": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "YesNo"
    }
}
```

I now also have the requirement to include a PDF attachment as part of the same request. I am looking for the most efficient way to do this. Encoding the attachment into the above JSON using either BSON, Base64 etc. does not seem the right way to go. I am looking for something that is more compact and efficient.

What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you must have the PDF as part of the same response then I don't think there are any good alternatives. I see BSON, Base64, and mime-multipart responses as your options, and I think they're all bad. Be especially wary of mime-multipart, as it's poorly supported on older browsers.

Most APIs have a separate resource that streams the file back. Is there some compelling reason it must be the same request?